# Conditionally typing the return value of a returned function based on a closure value

Tags: typescript

In one of my projects, I've written a generic higher order function (A) which returns a function (B).

I'm trying to get the return type of B to be conditionally dependent on an inferred generic parameter of A. Here is a minimal example of the problem I'm having:

```
const higherOrderFunction =
  <T extends Record<string, unknown> | undefined>(optional?: T) =>
  (): T extends undefined ? undefined : T =>
    optional; // Type Error :-(
```

At the moment, if I don't explicitly provide a return type for B, TypeScript is inferring a return type of `Record<string, unknown> | undefined`.

This is what I want

```
const b = higherOrderFunction()
const result = b() // type is 'undefined'
```

```
const b = higherOrderFunction({foo, 'bar'})
const result = b() // type is '{foo, 'bar'}'
```

The error I'm seeing is:

```
Type T | undefined is not assignable to type 'T extends undefined ? T : undefined'. 
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'T extends undefined ? T : undefined'`
```

Any help on this matter would be gratefully received!

Comment: @kaya3 perhaps I've typed the function itself incorrectly then, but I've explained the behaviour I want in the question quite clearly so perhaps you could answer it?

Comment: OK, I think I've figured it out. I'll write an answer.

Comment: I've described it wrong, maybe. But if you just read from "this is what I want", its very clear what I'm trying to achieve.

I had assumed that the `T` in the returned function would retain the type that was inferred from A.

Comment: I think it would be help: `const higherOrderFunction =
  <T extends Record<string, unknown> | undefined>(optional?: T) =>
  ()=> optional;`. [PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&ssl=3&ssc=17&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAFgSwOZwKYCcDy6AmGBiArmMFAuDALwBQMMAPACoyoAeUqYOEMASqqFz1o6BGCQAaGMQDWYEAHcwAPhgAfaV1QAzMahzKAFCAAOZcAEMANgH4AXDEYBKKstoxDTyqtPmw1gG5qYNBIWAAjKnhkNCxcAmJScjBPalDoGHRUCEIrWEoYcM8YAHoSmCgATxNUGAQeAHJiPF0wfQaQ8AgQK1QAOisQJEMsnLynILSuiIBGKMQUDGw8dCISP0MAb20QEAcG8It0BoBfJymwzOzcqDmC8Jnisorq2vqYBu3dqQOj046Lt1egMhiNrnkZk4gA)

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi nope, that doesn't work. The playground link you sent me infers `| undefined` types for both return values

Comment: Really. I see for first one `undefined` and for second one: `"foo": "bar"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional type `T extends undefined ? undefined : T` is equivalent to `T` (except possibly in some rare edge cases). So that's why it's not working; the parameter `optional` is of type `T | undefined` so it's not assignable to a return type that's (basically) `T`.

I think what you want to achieve makes most sense to describe with function overloads:

```
function higherOrderFunction(): () => undefined;
function higherOrderFunction<T>(value: T): () => T;
function higherOrderFunction(value?: unknown) {
    return () => value;
}
```

Note that without an `as const` assertion you'll get `{foo: string}`, not `{foo: 'bar'}` for the type, but otherwise this seems to be what you are looking for.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACxgc2QUwE4HlsAmOAYuNPGABQCUAXIjYgLwB8i4RwMYmBA3AChQkWAhToseQiTKiwAHgAqLSgDcAhgBsQmeoroNqzNosHDyY1Bhz4i2UiIpqtOgPz1wAazBwA7mCMAbwFEUMRsTCgQbCRGVkQNbUxBAF8BdIgEAGcoRAAjAEZmcWspOwcLKmoBTLAc8MwskE0oIqZ8gsYAei7EKABPAAdMRBgsxAByDkwuHgIJjOzcvIAmYqtJWxlHBEpA4Dg4egm89WwJlOra+oimlrX21e7egeHR8Yn9w-oc7G40FITIA)